# Classifier options greyed out in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, classification, weka

I have numeric data which has missing values. I want to classify the data using Naive Bayes Classifier in Weka but the option is grayed out. Please help.

Answer (score 10):

If a classifier is grayed out, it means that it doesn't support the kind of task you want to do. This could be because of the type of features or because of the type of predictions you want to make.

In your case it could be that you're trying to predict a numeric instead of a categorical attribute.

Comment: putting the target variable in the end worked. Apparently weka always requires the target feature to be at the end of the line.

Comment: @anonuser0428 the class parameter is supposed to be the last one *when it's not specified*. You can configure it with `Instances.setClass()` method (in Java), or through options in the classifiers (when available).

Comment: and what about the procedure which Naive Bayes deals with missing values? Deletes records or columns with missing values?